# Android : Video Download From Server but how to restriction share and out side app acess like Youtube download video .

Tags: android, encryption

I am developing a video player where downloaded video tutorials have to be played offline.

I want to secure these video files. What is the best and economical way to encrypt these files per user

once user get video, they can share it with others. I want to restrict that.

Please suggest me some ideas of how I can protect these videos from piracy.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You could create a key per user and encrypt the file with that before downloading it into the user device. Using the same key you could decrypt the file while playing in you app

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion  but give me source code if it possible. or give me any idea of code how to do .